# Make input field always centered

Tags: html, css, input, responsive

This is so simple, or seems like it, but I cannot get it.

I'm simply trying to always keep my form `input centered`, and be `responsive` to changes in the `window size`.

Instead, it stays to the `left`.

Here is html and css code below:-

```css
    #teaser-input{
     max-width:100%;
    }
     #teaser-input input{
      margin:auto;
      font-size:2.0em;
      color:#36393D;
      text-align:center;
    
     }
```

```html
    <div id="teaser-input">
     <form>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="Notify me at: you@provider.com">
     </form>
    </div><!--teaser-input-->
```

Comment: Add text-align:center to parent...

Comment: I wish it was that easy, this isnt responsive..

Comment: `#teaser-input {
        max-width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }`

This worked for me. What exactly do you mean by "not responsive"?

Comment: if i resize the window, the input box remains the same size (and overflows)

Comment: You can't have 'responsive' font, afaik, without additional scripting.

Comment: #teaser-input{
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
    #teaser-input input{
        margin:auto;
        font-size:2.0em;
        color:#36393D;
        text-align:center;
        **max-width:100%;**
    }

Comment: Im saying the actual box itself.

Comment: Set max-width to input field, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/zkb2627x/

Comment: **Try this** #teaser-input{width:100%; max-width:320px;text-align:center; display:block; margin:0px auto;} #teaser-input input{width:100%} hope helps you.

Comment: @nevermind - that worked well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a CSS trick, flexbox. You could if the solution is what you wanted. The textbox now moves according to the page width. I've changed the structure of the form as well as such that the `<div>` is inside the `<form>` now.

HTML:

```
<form class="flexbox">
<div class="stretch" >
    <input type="text" name="email" value="Notify me at: you@provider.com">
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.flexbox { display: flex;  text-align:center; max-width:100%;  }
.flexbox .stretch { flex: 1; }
.flexbox div input {
        width: 50%;
        font-size:2.0em;
        color:#36393D;
        text-align:center;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkb2627x/1/

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, albeit it isnt responsive. Thoughts on how to accomplish that for the input box?

Comment: @Jshee just updated the answer, is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I added `display: block;` for the `input` element in your CSS and it worked, see: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/komxz4dv/)

Also, you can resize the screen and it's responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox ,

```
justify-content: center;
```

will align item exactly on center of element.

```css
#teaser-input{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
    #teaser-input input{
        margin:auto;
        font-size:2.0em;
        color:#36393D;
        width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="teaser-input">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="Notify me at: you@provider.com">
    </form>
</div><!--teaser-input-->
```